# Why is the function overload that takes an int preferred over the one taking an unsigned char?

Tags: c++, overloading

Consider this program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f(unsigned char c) {
  cout << c << endl;
}

void f(int c) {
  cout << c << endl;
}

int main() {
  f('a');
}
```

This prints out `97`, suggesting that the `f()` overload that was selected was the one taking an `int`. I find this weird; wouldn't intuitively an `unsigned char` be a better match for a `char`?

Comment: it's because on your compiler char == signed char

Comment: I can't find a proper duplicate, but there probably is one.  what you're looking for is how conversion sequences are handled.

Comment: This is similar and should help explain things. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166131/why-does-the-compiler-match-char-to-int-but-not-short

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> wouldn't intuitively an `unsigned char` be a better match for a `char`?

Well, I guess, but not according to the Standard. According to [`[conv.prom]p1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv#prom-1):

> A prvalue of an integer type other than `bool`, `char16_­t`, `char32_­t`, or `wchar_­t` whose integer conversion rank is less than the rank of int can be converted to a prvalue of type `int` if `int` can represent all the values of the source type; [...]

Now, the three character types have the same rank, and a signed type has a rank always less than `int`. This is a combination of [`[conv.rank]p1.6`](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.rank#1.6) and [`[conv.rank]p1.2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.rank#1.2):

> - The rank of a signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of any signed integer type with a smaller size.
> - [...]
> - The rank of `char` shall equal the rank of `signed char` and `unsigned char`.

Basically, every character has always a smaller rank than `int` and they  can all be represented in an `int`, and so the overload with `unsigned char` is not a better match, because it would involve a conversion from `char` to `unsigned char`, instead of a promotion.

If you change your overload to take a `char`, then there would be an exact match, and so naturally, the "correct" overload (in your eyes) would be chosen.

Comment: There is also a good reference [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), section *"Ranking of implicit conversion sequences"*. It basically says that integer/floating-point promotion is preferred over conversion.